# Compiling php extensions for MAMP

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, phpize

I need to install a couple of PHP extensions, like memcache and geoip, on MAMP 3.5, for PHP 5.6.10.

What I'm doing is to run phpize:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/phpize
```

Which outputs:

> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20131106
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20131226
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

Then configure:

```
/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php-config
```

And, afterwards, try to build with make. This is where I get this error:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/include/php/Zend/zend.h:51:11: fatal error: 'zend_config.h' file not found
```

I downloaded the content of the include/php folder from php.net, version 5.6.10 (found [here](http://php.net/get/php-5.6.10.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)).

I feel I'm closer now to solving this problem, but I'm at loss with this error. What am I doing wrong, so that apparently the freshly downloaded php from php.net is missing files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using pecl instead of manually compiling the extensions.

The headers missing on the make step were I didn't run ./configure on the php folder - I came across this step by chance, really.

Afterwards, all I had to do was run:

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/pecl install memcache
```

And everything was running on wheels.

Before trying pecl, I tried to run make as I was doing on my post, and the extension compiled successfully, but I had versions mismatch between the php and the extension. I had previously tried pecl without success, but I don't really know what changed in my configuration since I last tried.

---

Anyway, I wrote a [gist](https://gist.github.com/imcarvalho/b8af4622380aa5310499) with all my steps to get this working, in case anyone has the same problem and is a complete beginner on this subject like I am.